# Status bar orientation value is __C.UIInterfaceOrientation

Tags: ios, swift

I am using the following code to retrieve the orientation :

```
let currentOrientation = UIApplication.shared.statusBarOrientation
```

But the value retrieved in some cases is : `__C.UIInterfaceOrientation`.

---

What could be the reason for this, as I cannot obtain the current orientation to update the User interface accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

```
let abc = UIApplication.shared.statusBarOrientation
        print(abc.isLandscape)
        print(abc.isPortrait)
```

Check if currentOrientation is isLandscape or isPortrait or not.

[image]